# How to get and set as variable one value from JSON file in Windows Batch

Tags: json, windows, batch-file, extract

**So**, basically i have a JSON file

```
{"date":"2020-01-25","explanation":"In this Hubble Space Telescope image the bright, spiky stars lie in the foreground toward the heroic northern constellation Perseus and well within our own Milky Way galaxy. In sharp focus beyond is UGC 2885, a giant spiral galaxy about 232 million light-years distant. Some 800,000 light-years across compared to the Milky Way's diameter of 100,000 light-years or so, it has around 1 trillion stars. That's about 10 times as many stars as the Milky Way. Part of a current investigation to understand how galaxies can grow to such enormous sizes, UGC 2885 was also part of astronomer Vera Rubin's pioneering study of the rotation of spiral galaxies. Her work was the first to convincingly demonstrate the dominating presence of dark matter in our universe.","hdurl":"https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/2001/RubinsGalaxy_hst2000.jpg","media_type":"image","service_version":"v1","title":"Rubin's Galaxy","url":"https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/2001/RubinsGalaxy_hst1024.jpg"}
```

It's a NASA APOD Api. I want to get that one particular "hdurl" value and set it as a URL Variable inside batch: "https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/2001/RubinsGalaxy_hst2000.jpg"

Then i want it to download the image from that site.

I honestly have no idea how i'm supossed to do it.
Any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2 time the for loop:

1st delimiters **`:}`** in **`for`** loop, and **`;`** (default) in 2nd  **`for`** loop 2nd:

- **In command line:**

```cmd
for /f tokens^=4*delims^=^:^} %i in ('type file.json')do for /f tokens^=1delims^=^"^  %I in ('echo/%i%j')do echo/%I && set "_imageURL=%I"
```

- **In File [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)**/**[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)**

```cmd
@echo off 

for /f tokens^=4*delims^=^:^} %%i in ('type file.json
')do for /f tokens^=1delims^=^"^  %%I in ('echo/%%i%%j')do echo/%%I && set "_imageURL=%%I"
```

---

- **Outputs:**

  ---

```cmd
https//apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/2001/RubinsGalaxy_hst2000.jpg
```

---

```cmd
{"date":"2020-01-25","explanation":"In this Hubble Space Telescope image the bright, spiky stars lie in the foreground toward the heroic northern constellation Perseus and well within our own Milky Way galaxy. In sharp focus beyond is UGC 2885, a giant spiral galaxy about 232 million light-years distant. Some 800,000 light-years across compared to the Milky Way's diameter of 100,000 light-years or so, it has around 1 trillion stars. That's about 10 times as many stars as the Milky Way. Part of a current investigation to understand how galaxies can grow to such enormous sizes, UGC 2885 was also part of astronomer Vera Rubin's pioneering study of the rotation of spiral galaxies. Her work was the first to convincingly demonstrate the dominating presence of dark matter in our universe.","hdurl":"https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/2001/RubinsGalaxy_hst2000.jpg","media_type":"image","service_version":"v1","title":"Rubin's Galaxy","url":"https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/2001/RubinsGalaxy_hst1024.jpg"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use a tool that understands JSON. If you like, you could give [`xidel`](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) a try.

```
xidel -s input.json -e "$json/hdurl"
https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/2001/RubinsGalaxy_hst2000.jpg
```

This simple extraction query returns the url you want.

To assign this url to a variable you could do it the old-fashioned way...

```
FOR /F "delims=" %A IN ('xidel -s input.json -e "$json/hdurl"') DO SET URL=%A
```

...or let `xidel` do it for you...

```
FOR /F "delims=" %A IN ('xidel -s input.json -e "URL:=$json/hdurl" --output-format^=cmd') DO %A
```

*(be sure to use `%%A` instead of `%A` when you use this command in a Batch-script)*

To download the jpg-file you can again use `xidel`.

```
xidel -s input.json -f "$json/hdurl" --download="."
```

This downloads *'RubinsGalaxy_hst2000.jpg'* to the current dir.